# static LIST of class returning same value

Tags: c#

I have two classes, one contains the value I want to maintain and it is declared as [serializable] since I may want to store the results in a file later.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1
    {
        string Something = "";

        public Class1(string something)
        {
            Something = something;
        }
        public Class1()
        {
            Something = "";
        }
        public string something
        {
            get { return Something; }
            set { Something = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The second declares a List of this class along with a few access functions

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Class2
    {
        public static List<Class1> aClass = new List<Class1>();
        public static int cnt = 0;

        public void AddStaticString(Class1 aString)
        {
            aClass.Add(aString);
            cnt++;
        }
        public string GetAllStrings()
        {
            string aFullString = "";
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt < aClass.Count)
            {
                aFullString = aClass[cnt].something;
                cnt++;
            }
            return aFullString;
        }
    }
}
```

Now a simple bit of code to add to the LIST and try to extract it

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 aClass = new Class1();
            Class2 aSClass = new Class2();

            aClass.something = "AAAAA";
            aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

            aClass.something = "BBBBB";
            aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

            aClass.something = "CCCCC";
            aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

            richTextBox1.Text = aSClass.GetAllStrings();
        }
    }
}
```

The richTextBox always displays the last item only (CCCCC), even though I can see the proper values being input into the LIST.

Can I not access the members of the LIST with `aFullString = aClass[cnt].something;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are just returning the last string from the list in `GetAllStrings`. Rather you could append it to existing item, or maybe separate them using comma, whatever you want.

For example, you can append those values using simply:

```
aFullString += aClass[cnt].something + ",";
```

But that would leave a comma at the end of the string.

Rather, if you need comma separated values, you could just join the strings using LINQ,

```
public string GetAllStrings()
{
    return string.Join(",", aClass.Select(item => item.something));
}
```

---

Also, in `button1_Click` you are adding the same instance of `Class1` to the list in `Class2`. If you need separate instances of the class, you should create new instance before calling `AddStaticString`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class2 aSClass = new Class2();

    Class1 aClass = new Class1();
    aClass.something = "AAAAA";
    aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

    aClass = new Class1();
    aClass.something = "BBBBB";
    aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

    aClass = new Class1();
    aClass.something = "CCCCC";
    aSClass.AddStaticString(aClass);

    richTextBox1.Text = aSClass.GetAllStrings();
}
```

Comment: This returns CCCCC,CCCCC,CCCCC

Comment: @D.Haskins Hmm I just noticed the problem in `button1_Click` as well. Basically if you don't create new instance of the class, the value of `something` field is overridden. So all three values in the list point to the same instance of `Class1`, hence you get the same string appearing thrice in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should, but the way you are assigning that `aFullString` variable will always show the last value of the list.

You should try it like this:

```
public string GetAllStrings()
    {
        string aFullString = "";
        int cnt = 0;
        while (cnt < aClass.Count)
        {             //+ to keep the previous values too
            aFullString += aClass[cnt].something;
            cnt++;
        }
        return aFullString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
public string GetAllStrings()
{
    string aFullString = "";
    int cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < aClass.Count)
    {
        aFullString = aClass[cnt].something;
        cnt++;
    }
    return aFullString;
}
```

You set `aFullString` to the last collection item's `something`.

What you want is probably string concatenation. You don't need `while` loop - `for` or `foreach` loop suit better, or even `string.Join` would be the best option:

```
public string GetAllStrings()
{
    return String.Join(" ", aClass.Select(x => x.something);
}
```

Please, note that your code has many style and naming errors, unused or useless variables like class members `Something` and `cnt`, and doesn't make much sense in general.
You need to follow C# naming conventions and rules to make your code readable and understandable by other developers.